# Hibernate false negative read

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a web application that consists of a web service with two operations: `createA` and `createB`. An handler is registered for the endpoint. This handler opens a Session and start a transaction when the request is received. Then the code of the requested operation is executed. Before the response is sent back, the transaction is committed and the session is closed.

The code of `createA` consists of creating an entity of type `A` and persisting it using `Session.save()` method. In DEBUG mode, after `Session.save()` is called, I can see that there is one insertion in the ActionQueue of the session.

The code of `createB` consists of :

- retrieving the previously created entity of type `A`
- creating an Entity `B` that references the instance of `A` (B has a property that represents an associated `A`)
- updating `A` to reference the new instance of `B`
- call `Session.save()` for the new instance of `B`
- call `Session.update()` for the new modified instance of `A`

However, in DEBUG mode, after calling `Session.save()` and `Session.update()`, the ActionQueue of the corresponding Session is empty. But, after the transaction commits, I can see the created entity in the database.

Operation `createA` and `createB` are invoked in this order without DEBUG. An error appears during the execution of the create `B` when it tries to retrieve the instance of `A` previously created using a criteria and the `Session.list()` method. The problem is that the instance of `A` is not found.

However, if I repeat the same sequence of operations in DEBUG or using `Thread.sleep(15s)` between invocations of the two operations, the instance of `A` can be found.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**: I forgot to precise that it works on certain machines but not on others. And I don't see any differences between these machines.

Comment: Whether both the operations `createA` and `createB` are happening with in the same transaction and are running in the same thread?

Comment: @ArunPJohny On the client side, the operations are invoked in the specified order in the same thread. On the server side, I think they are invoked in different threads since it is a web service hosted on Tomcat. Concerning transactions, the two operations use two different Session and therefore use two different transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same Hibernate session for both createA and createB, then it'll work. You can store the Hibernate session in the Http session for achieving this (pay attention to synchronize the access to the session object, as requests from the same browser session can com in different threads).

Your problem is, Hibernate opens a new database connection for every session. Now your database seems not to synchronize the statements. It can happen in the database the select arrives before the insert is finished. Then it just depends of the speed of the involved computers if this condition happens or not. With the debug mode or the sleep() you make one computer slower so you don't have the problem any more.

If you want to continue with two different sessions for these two procedures, you can

- look for the transaction mode of your database. Some databases have a dirty read where no correct locking or synchronization is done. Check if you accidentally used such a mode.
- Check the JDBC parameters (they can be used in the hibernate connection.url) if there are parameters for your database which change timing and synchronization.
- Check your connection pool (for the case you're using one).

Comment: Thanks. What should I check in my database? Transaction isolation level? If yes, I use the default value for MySQL with InnoDB (REPEATABLE_READ). What should I check concerning connection pooling?

Comment: Try READ-COMMITTED or SERIALIZABLE as transaction isolation level. For  MySQL there is a good documentation available, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html , also have a look into chapter 14.6.8 in the same documentation. Perhaps you can set the isolation mode in the JDBC connection string. - The connection pooling just was an idea, because it is also involved here (for example c3p0), but I never had to have a closer look there.

Comment: I've tried SERIALIZABLE as transaction isolation level which is the most restrictive but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Hibernate does not save the entity to the database when you call Session.save(). It simply prepares the statement for execution later. This happens when you the transaction ends or when the you flush the session.

Your call to B is probably happening sometimes before the transaction ends for the A request. That is why it works if you wait a little while.

Try adding session.flush() after the save call. This will force Hibernate to persist the changes to the DB.

Comment: I use FLUSHMODE = COMMIT, so the modifications are flushed when the transaction commits. And I don't call createB before committing the transaction of createA. The question is when the flush is done after the commit? Is it done before the commit() method returns? If not, it may be that the changes are not yet present in the DB when create B is called.

Comment: The flush must be happening otherwise the object would never get into the database. You should try explicitly flushing and see if it works. It could be that the call for B is happening before the container has completed the request for A.

Comment: Do you mean that if I call Session.flush() before the commit, I can be sure that the SQL statements have been executed in the database before commiting or it works in a multi-thread model?

Comment: I mean the next line after session.save call session.flush().

Comment: I understand. My question was: if I call Session.flush() before the commit, can I be sure that the SQL statements have been executed in the database before the Session.flush() method returns?

Comment: I've tested to call Session.flush() before the commit and the issue still happens. Maybe Hibernate doesn't really execute the flush because the FLUSHMODE is COMMIT?

Comment: I've also tried to change the FLUSHMODE to AUTO and doing the Session.flush() before the commit but it still doesn't help.